# Linux Shell: How do I overload the echo command?

Tags: shell, operating-system, exploit

I created a file with
`echo "/bin/sh" > cp`

Made it an executable and updated the $PATH variable to consider the current folder first.
`chmod +x cp export PATH=.:$PATH`

The program cp is overloaded over the default command. And I got a shell anytime i ran the cp command.

But when I try to recreate the same results with the echo command. It fails to overload. I can't figure out the reason for such a behaviour.
[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLJS2.png)

I've tried renaming the cp program as the echo command. And it still failed to produce the same results.

Comment: `export PATH=.:$PATH` is a *really* bad idea. As is your "overloading".

Comment: And shells sometimes have internal commands, commands that are fully handled by the shell themselves, not as external programs. `echo` seems to be such a command for your shell, while `cp` seems to be the standard `/bin/cp` program.